# Capture screen and stream to RTMP server

Tags: c#, streaming, live, rtmp

I would like to play around with coding an application that could capture a desktop or section of a screen (height and width variables for resolution) and stream those to an RTMP server (rtmp://server.com/live)

I'd prefer for this fun project to be available on Windows, so I'm thinking C# for its ability to make really nice professional looking GUIs.

Anyway, without all the fancy features like overlays or authentication, I just want to take a section of a screen and send the appropriate information to an open RTMP server like Flash Media Server.

Are these things built-in to C#? How do all of these streaming programs (Flash Media Live Encoder, Xsplit, Procaster, etc work? This is probably my starting point.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319378/rtmp-c-sharp-client-library

Comment: Thank you. When a product like FlourineFX says "free and open source", what does that mean if I theoretically ever made a real product with a team and tried to sell it?

Comment: The answer to that depends on the [license](http://www.fluorinefx.com/license.html) of the package you choose to use. In this case, FluorineFX is licensed LGPL so my understanding is that you can use it in commercial products as long as you don't make any changes to or claim ownership of the library. If you do make changes to the library then you must be disclose the source changes made and make them freely available as well.

Comment: FlourineFX Publish functionality is not there in there latest code. It only says so in their documentaion. As far as borrocoli products are concerned..they only cover playing streaming video from Media Server but not streaming to the media server!. If anyone knows any library in .NET that allows to stream or publish video to an RTMP based Medis Server then please do share. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ffsplit is somewhat similar to what you're looking for.  I'd checkout ffmpeg and https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free as well.  I'm unaware of any high quality rtmp implementations in directshow...and that wouldn't be C# anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It have some application can do this task:
1. You user a vurtual webcam to capture what you want ( ManyCam Pro can do this)
2. Use Adobe Flash Media Encoder to get the stream from the camera above and put this to FMS server, it is RTMP.

Regards.